# How To Do path planning To move the Robotic Arm in straight line in 3D where the arm is having base, Shoulder, Elbow & wrist?

Tags: inverse-kinematics, industrial-robot, path-planning, automation

Now the design we have has the 4 DOF (Base, Shoulder, Elbow, Wrist), there is no problem in moving the arm in a curved manner but the main problem arises in straight-line motion. I'm unable to fid=nd the solution for that. the main concern is which at least 2 motors I should move.
Hoping For Solutions Here.
Regards.

Comment: Welcome to RoboticsLSE. I'm afraid that *Unbounded Design Questions* are off-topic here because there are many ways to solve any given design problem. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so questions which ask for a list of approaches or a subjective recommendation on a method (for how to build something, how to accomplish something, what something is capable of, etc.) are off-topic. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works.

Answer (score 1):

You need inverse kinematics. Which refers to calculating the joint angles so that the robot will reach a particular pose.

You can not simply move from point A to point B..
You will need to use inverse kinematics to calculate all the positions the arm will pass thru to form a straight line.

Comment: Thank you for your response! We are using the geometrical method for calculating IK for our system. Is it the right approach? or we supposed to go for the algebraic method?